# Why Android radio button's android:button property is not working for samsung tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

In my application I have used radio button and customise its icon by using android:button property. This is working fine with all the devices except SM-T5. It was working with Tablet before implementation of kotlin into it.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_log_detail"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/basic_color">
  <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/button_table"
      android:minWidth="55dp"
      android:minHeight="55dp"
      android:button="@drawable/table"
      android:background="@color/glp_basic_color"
      android:layout_margin="2dp"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:checked="true" />
```

Output:
For other devices table image is showing but for this device it is showing just a rounded radio button.

[image: **Screenshot**]

Comment: Could u add screenshots

Comment: @ArunAbimanyu added screenshot

Comment: Thanks Could u add table drawable file code

Comment: It is just an image png file